# How to add underscore before the text in textBox TextChange?

Tags: c#

How should I put it into the program that it will add underscore before the text that is encoded in the textbox?

Kindly see the below code.

```
private void textBoxP1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBoxP1 = "_" + textBoxP1.Text;

}
```

No error came out from this code but this does not automatically add the underscore before the text.

Thank you.

Comment: _No error came out from this code_ I really doubt it.

Comment: OT Maybe you also want to check that there wasn't already an underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you want to use `.Text` as @nvoigt pointed out. Otherwise it won't work.
Secondly you might want to check when to add underscore and only then add it:

```
private void textBoxP1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(this.textBoxP1.Text) && this.textBoxP1.Text[0] != '_')
    {
       this.textBoxP1.Text = $"_{this.textBoxP1.Text}";
    }
}
```

Assignign property `Text` will trigger the event once again but since we have `_` prefix this time it won't go inside the if.

Comment: I appreciate your advice Fabjan. Thank you.

Comment: It works Fabjan. I'm a newbie to C# and programming.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `.Text`:

```
this.textBoxP1.Text = "_" + this.textBoxP1.Text;
```

---

If this actually is the changed handler for the text box as the naming suggests, you need a break condition. Otherwise, changing the text to have an underscore in front will trigger the change handler again... and again... and again...

As you only want a single underscore, you may want to check that and not add any underscores if your text already starts with one.

Comment: but this code will produce `changed times` count `_`s.

Comment: I would add a note about the fact that this code is inside a TextChanged event handler , so at each keystroke....

Comment: Yes, correct, I forgot the .Text after this. I tried to correct but the error occurred "{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}"

Comment: By assigning to `textBoxP1.Text` you will trigger the `textChanged` event again. This leads to infinite recursion and a stack overflow. Doing this only if there is no underscore already would fix this problem, too.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate it